# How to add option that will accept string discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I can't find a solution to my problem. I want to create a `change_nick` command and I don't know the type/number of this option to use.

My command creator:

```js
commands.create
            (
                {
                    name: 'change_nick',
                    description: 'changes nick for specified person',
                    options:
                    [
                        {
                            name: 'user',
                            description: 'user that name will be changed',
                            type: 6,
                        },
                        {
                            name: "new_username",
                            description: "new username",
                            type: "" //that's what I'm searching for,
                        },
                    ]
                },
            );
```

I tried browsing and reading the documentation but I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

If you want to accept a string, then it's number 3:

```js
commands.create({
  name: 'change_nick',
  description: 'changes nick for specified person',
  options: [
    {
      name: 'user',
      description: 'user that name will be changed',
      type: 6,
    },
    {
      name: 'new_username',
      description: 'new username',
      type: 3, //that's what I'm searching for,
    },
  ],
});
```

| type | value |
| --- | --- |
| Attachment | 11 |
| Boolean | 5 |
| Channel | 7 |
| Integer | 4 |
| Mentionable | 9 |
| Number | 10 |
| Role | 8 |
| String | 3 |
| Subcommand | 1 |
| SubcommandGroup | 2 |
| User | 6 |

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#application-command-object-application-command-option-type) say it's type 3.
In discord.js you can also do this:
**v13**
`const { Constants } = require('discord.js');`
and then use
`Constants.ApplicationCommandOptionTypes.STRING`
**v14**
`const { ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');`
and then use
`ApplicationCommandOptionType.String`